# execute operator on pointer without dereferencing

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have variable buff which has overloaded = operator.
this variable is used in lambda and passed by pointer.
when i want to use this operator I would do:

```
*buf=CreateBuffer(w, h, type, c);
```

However it dereferences pointer and destructor is called at the end of scope which shouldn't happen.

So to prevent invocation of destructor I do:

```
buf->operator=(CreateBuffer(w, h, type, c));
```

is there any other normal convention to achieve =operator without this long version?

Comment: Does `CreateBuffer` return whatever type `*buf` is by value? Then you can't really prevent the destructor being called as the return of `CreateBuffer` creates a temporary object that needs to be destructed in both cases. I really doubt that is the *root* problem you have, perhaps if you give more detail as to *why* you don't want the destructor to be called we can help you better? What is the *actual* problem you're having? Do you have problems because you don't follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: If `buf` is a regular pointer then those are exactly equivalent. (Both are `(*buf).operator=(CreateBuffer(w, h, type, c));`.) Please post the relevant code instead of describing it.

Answer (score 1):

> execute operator on pointer

Your operator isn't overloaded for the pointer, but for the pointed type. Therefore you cannot "execute operator on pointer". To execute the operator on the pointed object, you must dereference the pointer either by using `*` or `->`.

> However it dereferences pointer and destructor is called at the end of scope which shouldn't happen.

Dereferencing a pointer does not cause a destructor to be called unless you have a strange overload for `operator*` (which you cannot have if `buf` is a primitive pointer, rather than a wrapper class).

I suspect, that you are observing the destructor of a temporary, that is created due to conversion from `CreateBuffer` into `decltype(*buf)`, although it is impossible to be sure without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).